# Load Testing Response message: Non HTTP response message: Truncated chunk (expected size: 13,913,367; actual size: 878,527)

Tags: jmeter

Thread Name: Thread Group 1-5
Sample Start: 2019-10-17 10:46:49 IST
Load time: 25806
Connect Time: 28
Latency: 22280
Size in bytes: 1291
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1291
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Truncated chunk (expected size: 13,913,367; actual size: 878,527)

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8

This Error Shows i Dont know about this issue lindly help me..

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [`chunked` directive documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#Directives)

> Data is sent in a series of chunks. The [Content-Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) header is omitted in this case and at the beginning of each chunk you need to add the length of the current chunk in hexadecimal format, followed by `\r\n` and then the chunk itself, followed by another `\r\n`. The terminating chunk is a regular chunk, with the exception that its length is zero. It is followed by the trailer, which consists of a (possibly empty) sequence of entity header fields.

So it appears you're getting an incomplete response, most probably your application is overloaded and fails to properly respond, I would recommend checking your application logs and setting up monitoring of its baseline health metrics like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk usage, etc. It can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)